# Mock IJSRuntime InvokeVoidAsync

Tags: javascript, c#, blazor, moq, xunit

I want to mock `InvokeVoidAsync` from C# Blazor `IJSRuntime` with using `xunit` and `Moq`. So far I have a simple function to test that calls `await _js.InvokeVoidAsync("register")`, where `_js` is an object of type `IJSRuntime`.

My test looks like the following:

```
[Fact]
public async Task Register_Test()
{
    var jsMock = new Mock<IJSRuntime>();
    jsMock.Setup(x => x.InvokeAsync<object>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object[]>())).Returns(new ValueTask<object>());

    ...

    jsMock.Verify(x => x.InvokeAsync<bool>("register"), Times.Once());
}
```

Note that I do not call `InvokeVoidAsync` directly as stated [here](https://www.cognizantsoftvision.com/blog/mocking-injected-types-in-blazor/) and I'm trying to apply the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67220948/mock-xunit-testing-ijsruntime) that describes how to used `InvokeAsync<type>`.

This test compiles, but while executing I get an error saying

```
System.InvalidCastException : Unable to cast object of type 'System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[System.Object]' to type 'System.Threading.Tasks.ValueTask`1[Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.IJSVoidResult]'.
```

How can I call and test `InvokeVoidAsync` from `IJSRuntime`?

Comment: Try `.ReturnsAsync` instead of `Returns`.  Or `Returns(Task.FromResult(new ValueTask<object>())`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error message was quite helpful.

The correct test would look like this:

```
{
    var jsMock = new Mock<IJSRuntime>();
    jsMock.Setup(x => x.InvokeAsync<Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.IJSVoidResult>(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<object[]>())).Returns(new ValueTask<Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.IJSVoidResult>());

    ...

    jsMock.Verify(x => x.InvokeAsync<Microsoft.JSInterop.Infrastructure.IJSVoidResult>("register"), Times.Once());
}
```